# Azure function output binding fails when connecting with Azure Storage instead of local emulated storage

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to implement azure functions output binding.

Below my code snippet which has 2 bindings. one uploads to storage and one and to storage queue.

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
                [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
                [Blob("general/uploaded-files/{rand-guid}.txt", FileAccess.Write)] Stream outputBlob,
                [Queue("my-queue")] ICollector<string> outputQueue,
                ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        // Read the file from the request
        var file = req.Form.Files["file"];
        if (file != null)
        {
            using var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream();
            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(outputBlob);

            // Add a message to the output queue
            string message = $"File '{file.FileName}' uploaded successfully.";
            outputQueue.Add(message);

            return new OkObjectResult(message);
        }

        return new BadRequestObjectResult("No file found in the request.");
    }
```

Its working fine locally and I am getting my files uploaded to my emulated storage accounts container and its posting message into storage queue.

Now my localsettings.json has this value

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    ...
    ...
```

But I updated AzureWebJobsStorage with real storage (ADLS2) connection string
in this format

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storagesample;AccountKey=<account-key>
```

But now I am getting an error in function console like this

```
[2023-04-21T18:20:23.149Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'e9686gd0d1-f23c-4e1c-b821-aa84d7cc331b0'.
[2023-04-21T18:20:23.151Z] Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: No valid combination of account information found.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
```

[image]

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage)  for the `AzureWebJobsStorage` configuration key straight up declares that a general purpose storage account is required as the Functions runtime requires tables and queues. As you mentioned ADLS2 - I presume you mean Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 as per  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction), this type of storage doesn't support at least one of the storage services required, whereas a general purpose storage account would support them all. Since the documentation talks at length about blobs but nothing at all about queues or tables, either the queue binding or the functions runtime itself could be generating that error as the particular storage service it needs is not supported.

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output#attributes), both the output bindings and the Function's internal state management store (pardon my not knowing the exact name of this) are both using the `AzureWebJobsStorage` connection string as per the precedence rules defined there.

To fix this, you would have to provision a general purpose storage account and set the queue binding to reference this storage account by its own connection string instead using the `Connection` property on the binding attribute, or the `StorageAccount` attribute, as well as pointing the functions runtime to this same storage account or a specially configured storage account using the `AzureWebJobsStorage` setting. Only the blob binding will be able to use a Data Lake storage account, also referring to it with its own `Connection` property or specific `StorageAccountAttribute`.